# Some icons (not all) are not showing on Firefox

Tags: font-awesome

For some reasons that I can't understand, some icons are not showing in Mozilla Firefox.. 
Other browsers like Safari (Osx and ios), Chrome and Opera are showing all icons.

Problem page on my site is - http://lightmuzikmastering.ru/order/

Just try this simple working code and you'll see a wrong icon in Mozilla...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://lightmuzikmastering.ru/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 </head> 
 <body>
<i class="fa fa-vk"></i>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the presence of an adblocking addon in Firefox. This issue is discussed at length [on the Font Awesome GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/1799).  If this is your problem, one solution is having a modified copy of the Font Awesome CSS file on your webserver, where you change the classnames of the icons that are being blocked.